# Dynamically expanding array using realloc

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, realloc

I have written following code to get clear with malloc and realloc.
I have initialized pointer using malloc and then using realloc, i am increasing the size of the array.
But i get following error when i run the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *p;
    p = malloc(10);
    p = " this is it";
    printf("\n%s", p);
    p = realloc(p, 14);
    p[11] = 'A';
    p[12] = 'B';
    p[13] = 'C';
    printf("\n %s", p) ;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ajay@ajay-K54L:~$ gcc te.c 
ajay@ajay-K54L:~$ ./a.out

*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: realloc(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000040071c ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7e626)[0x7fb111e88626]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(realloc+0x2de)[0x7fb111e8d3ee]
./a.out[0x4005dc]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7fb111e2b76d]
./a.out[0x4004d9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 3027043                            /home/ajay/a.out
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:03 3027043                            /home/ajay/a.out
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:03 3027043                            /home/ajay/a.out
00e76000-00e97000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fb111bf4000-7fb111c09000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 2100801                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fb111c09000-7fb111e08000 ---p 00015000 08:03 2100801                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fb111e08000-7fb111e09000 r--p 00014000 08:03 2100801                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fb111e09000-7fb111e0a000 rw-p 00015000 08:03 2100801                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fb111e0a000-7fb111fbd000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 2100780                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7fb111fbd000-7fb1121bc000 ---p 001b3000 08:03 2100780                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7fb1121bc000-7fb1121c0000 r--p 001b2000 08:03 2100780                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7fb1121c0000-7fb1121c2000 rw-p 001b6000 08:03 2100780                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7fb1121c2000-7fb1121c7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb1121c7000-7fb1121e9000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 2100760                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fb1123d2000-7fb1123d5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb1123e5000-7fb1123e9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb1123e9000-7fb1123ea000 r--p 00022000 08:03 2100760                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fb1123ea000-7fb1123ec000 rw-p 00023000 08:03 2100760                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7ffff08d4000-7ffff08f5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffff09ff000-7ffff0a00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
 this is itAborted (core dumped)
```

What am i doing wrong with memory allocation?
Thank you.

Comment: Regardless of any bugs in the code, [don't use realloc](http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/Why_not_realloc)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This:

```
p = " this is it"; /* Does not copy, use strcpy(). */
```

assigns the address of the string literal to `p`, changing it from the address returned previously by `malloc()`. The pointer being passed to [`realloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) must be:

> ... previously allocated by malloc(), calloc() or realloc() and not yet freed with free(), otherwise, the results are undefined.

Change the assignment to `strcpy()` for example to correct:

```
p = malloc(12); /* Increased size. */
if (p)
{
    strcpy(p, " this is it");
    char* tmp = realloc(p, 14);  /* Store result in temp to avoid potential */
    if (!tmp)                    /* in the event that realloc() fails. */
    {
        free(p);
        return -1;
    }
    p = tmp;
    /* snip ... */

    free(p); /* When 'p' is no longer required. */
}
```

Comment: Furthermore, " this is it" requires 12 bytes to store, so even strcpy would not work here as expected since only 10 bytes were allocated. Use [strncpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) (and be sure to allocated enough memory)

Comment: Ajay, depends what you're doing, but [realloc is probably not the answer](http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/Why_not_realloc). If it's delimited you can use [getdelim / getline](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) on some platforms or other variants on others. Often, pre-allocating a buffer of a certain size should be good enough.

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting the pointer returned by `malloc()`,  with a string:

```
p = " this is it";
```

You should use `strcpy()` to copy the string into the memory pointed at by `p`:

```
strcpy(p, "this is it");
```

Note, though, that the above string requires more space than you allocate: it's 10 visible characters, but strings have a 0-character as terminator so you need at least 11 characters of space.

Also, you should check the return value of both `malloc()` and `realloc()` before relying on the pointer being valid. If it's `NULL`, the allocation failed. This isn't very likely considering your allocation sizes, but it's good practice.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *p = malloc(10);
```

allocates the block of memory of size `10` and makes `p` point to this memory. Then

```
p = " this is it";
```

defines a constant string literal and makes `p` point to the read-only memory, where this constant string literal is stored. So

```
p = realloc(p, 14);
```

tries to `realloc` this read-only memory which produces **undefined behavior**.

---

Instead of assigning the address of constant string literal to `p` (which also procudes a **memory leak** since the address of the memory that you have dynamically allocated is lost), you should copy this string by using [`strcpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy). So replace this line:

```
p = " this is it";
```

with this:

```
strcpy(p, " this is it");
```