# Read File that you don't know the lenght of

Tags: c, c99

I have coded a program that reads an integers & tells if it's greater or not. I have done it with an array & initialized it with some numbers(As a test if the program works). Now I have to read it from a File with a lot of integers, but I don't know the length of the File. How can I determinate the size of the Array if I don't know the length?

Comment: If this is [Advent of Code](https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/1), mine was 2000 lines.

Comment: You could just look at the file ahead of time, or deliberately over allocate e.g. make space for 50000.

Comment: Or you can just remember the last number in the loop rather than reading in and storing the whole array - you only need to compare the current number to the last one, so you just need to store that one last number.

Comment: You don't need an array to determine the largest number.  Get unblocked on this by first writing a program that reads *one* integer from the file, and loops until eof.  If it is too slow then you'd consider buffering, but unlikely you need to when you use fopen().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you do it on the fly (read and process one line at a time -> one number at a time), or you need to allocate memory dynamically as you read the file as described here: [Dynamically expanding array using realloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090567/dynamically-expanding-array-using-realloc)

Comment: worked with malloc() thx

Answer (score -2):

Do you need to use an array? I think using list is your best option here. Than you can just use something like `myList.add(newElement)` or `myList.append(newElement)` depending on the language you are using.

Comment: never used lists so I can't really do it